# Import UI folder to lib folder files on flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing an app using flutter. My folder looks like this

```
-assets
-example
-lib
-test
-ui
-pubspec.yaml
-pubspec.lock
-CHANGELOG.md
-LICENSE
-README.md
```

I'm trying to access my ui folder to my examples and lib folders but i'm unable to do it successfully. How do I proceed to safetly import the folder to my files in the example and lib folders.

Comment: if ui contains dart files then you can't access them outside lib.